# How to change the default wallpaper on the custom LiveCD?

Tags: live-cd, desktop-background

I am trying to customize an 11.10 LiveCD.  Everything is working great, except I cannot figure out how to change the default wallpaper.  Which configuration file(s) do I need to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Ubuntu 12.04 :

Here's how you can change the default wallpaper. For example, we'll set it to the included **Wild Wheat** (`/usr/share/backgrounds/WildWheat_by_Brian_Burt.jpg`):

- Within the LiveCD `chroot`, open the following file with `nano` as,

  ```
  nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_gsettings-desktop-schemas.gschema.override
  ```
- Change the below line to the path for your file:

  ```
  picture-uri='file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
  ```
- For our example, that becomes:

  ```
  picture-uri='file:///usr/share/backgrounds/WildWheat_by_Brian_Burt.jpg`
  ```
- Finally, compile the modified `schemas` with:

  ```
  glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
  ```

### For Ubuntu 14.04 :

Say you want to make `/usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg` as your default wallpaper.

- Within the LiveCD `chroot`, open the following file with `nano` as,

  ```
  nano /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/ubuntu-wallpapers.xml
  ```
- Change the following line:

  ```
  <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png</filename>
  ```
- To (in our case):

  ```
  <filename>/usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg</filename>
  ```
- Also edit the `<stringvalue>` in the following file,

  ```
  nano /var/lib/gconf/debian.defaults/%gconf-tree.xml
  ```
- Change the line,

  ```
  <stringvalue>/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png</stringvalue>
  ```
- To (in our case):

  ```
  <stringvalue>/usr/share/backgrounds/Reflections_by_Trenton_Fox.jpg</stringvalue>
  ```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Custom_Background_for_GNOME)

Comment: This seems like it should work, but for some reason it isn't.  I suspect remastersys is doing something funny.

Comment: Yes, Remastersys is often problematic because of how it works compared to UCK or Ubuntu Builder. Perhaps try one of those?

Comment: With Ubuntu 13.10, it is `/usr/share/glib-2.0/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override` :)